# Trying to understand classes in c#

Tags: c#, class

New to C# and showing the world my lack of understanding (ignorance).  I have an SQL database with various tables.  In this case Category.  I have different queries that return different data for each table depending on the application.  For example I have a form to set up categories and then other forms use the categories in various ways.  To set up a category I have a class, Category.

```cs
using System;

namespace Toolcrib
{
    public partial class Globals
    {
        public class Category
        {
            private int categoryID;
            private string categoryDesc;
            private string shortCode;
            private bool isActive;
            private bool canDelete;
            private int idx;

            public Category()
            {
            }
            public Category (string CategoryDesc, string ShortCode, bool IsActive, bool CanDelete, int Idx)
            {
                categoryID = 0;
                categoryDesc = CategoryDesc;
                shortCode = ShortCode;                    
                isActive = IsActive;
                canDelete = CanDelete;
                idx = Idx;
            }

            public Category(int CategoryID, string CategoryDesc, string ShortCode, bool IsActive, bool CanDelete, int Idx)
            {
                categoryID = Convert.ToInt32(CategoryID);
                categoryDesc = CategoryDesc;
                shortCode = ShortCode;
                isActive = IsActive;
                canDelete = CanDelete;
                idx=Idx;
            }

            public int CategoryID
            {
                get { return categoryID; }
                set { categoryID = value; }
            }

            public string CategoryDesc
            {
                get { return categoryDesc; }
                set { categoryDesc = value; }
            }

            public string ShortCode
            {
                get { return shortCode; }
                set { shortCode = value; }
            }

            public bool IsActive
            {
                get { return isActive; }
                set { isActive = value; }
            }

            public bool CanDelete
            {
                get { return canDelete; }
                set { canDelete = value; }
            }

            public int Idx
            {
                get { return idx; }
                set { idx = value; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When using Category on other forms I don't need isActive, canDelete, or idx.  I may have misunderstood but I thought I could create a base class with only the categoryID, categoryDesc, and shortCode then when I implement it on my SetUpCategory form add to the class.  I have been looking but have not found a good example of how to make this work.  I can define two classes on for setup and one for implementation but, again, my thinking is that is not necessary.  Anyone who can point me in the right direction or provide a snippet of code will have my eternal gratitude.

Comment: First thing to note - if you changed all your properties to be automatically implemented properties, e.g. `public bool CanDelete { get; set; }` then your code would be about half the size...

Answer (score 0):

You must create the constructor for your need

```
public Category(int CategoryID, string CategoryDesc, string ShortCode)
{
    categoryID = Convert.ToInt32(CategoryID);
    categoryDesc = CategoryDesc;
    shortCode = ShortCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two separate use cases for your object:

1. One with `isActive`, `canDelete`, and `idx` (and possibly all other `Category` data).
2. One without `isActive`, `canDelete`, and `idx`.

To solve your problem, define two interfaces:

```
public interface ICategory
{
    int CategoryID { get; set; }
    string CategoryDesc { get; set; }
    string ShortCode { get; set; }
}

public interface ICategoryInfo : ICategory
{
    bool isActive { get; set; }
    bool canDelete { get; set; }
    int idx { get; set; }
}
```

Then, have your `Category` class implement those interfaces:

```
public class Category : ICategory, ICategoryInfo
```

Finally, wherever you need to use the `Category` class, instead of passing `Category`, pass either `ICategory` or `ICategoryInfo` as appropriate:

```
public void SaveCategory(ICategory category)
{
    // Do something awesome here.
}
```

Comment: What happens when I need to pass both?  When I set  up a category I need to to send SQL fields from both interfaces.  Also I have a method that converts a datatable to a list and that fails if I use an interface, I'm guessing that is an object issue.

Comment: In that case, your function takes an `ICategoryInfo`, and you pass it your `Category` instance. `ICategoryInfo` derives from `ICategory`, and contains all the properties you need for serialization to the database.